# HTML Table Border: User Agent style sheet overrides CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table that needs its border color changed. I can't figure it out.

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Conditions</th>
            <th>Characteristics</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="zebra-stripe">
            <td class="first-field">Element</td>
            <td>version}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first-field">ApplicationTransactionID</td>
            <td>string, up to 64 chars, Optional</td>
            <td>A number assigned by the calling application to uniquely identify this request.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
/* Global CSS */


table {
    border-color: red;
}

tr {
    border-color: red;
}

td {
    border-color: red;


/* Table CSS */

.zebra-stripe {
    border-color: red;
    background: #002D38;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.zebra-stripe table {
    border-color: red;
}

.zebra-stripe tr {
        border-color: red;
}

.zebra-stripe td {
        border-color: red;
}
```

I have even tried to change the border color with an inline style. Still no luck! It doesn't work in Chrome or Safari. The border is simply just gray and its from the user agent style sheet. Am I wrongly targeting it? I targeted it like 10 different ways. The class CSS should be enough. I can change the border style or the border width just fine, but I can't change the color. But at the most, targeting the table row should be enough as well.

Cannot fathom what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you haven't defined the rest of the border attributes. You can use:

```
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

(which is `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`)

instead of

```
table {
  border-color: red;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mLL817uv/1/)

Also a note about your current CSS, you have `.zebra-stripe` added as a class to a `tr` but the CSS states `.zebra-stripe table` and `.zebra-stripe tr` which means it's targeting a `table` or `tr` inside of a parent with a class of `.zebra-stripe`

**UPDATE**
To explain, there were 2 issues, 1 being you forgot to close this

```
tr {
  border-color: red;
}

td {
  border-color: red;
  <------ //no '}' tag
```

this prevented `.zebra-stripe` from working at all. Secondly, `.zebra-stripe` had the following issue:

```
.zebra-stripe
  border-color: red;
  background: #002D38;
  border: solid; <------ this should be 'border-style', 'border' is overwriting the others
  border-width: 1px;
```

Comment: Ahhh man that solved my problem! Thanks much jmore009

Just not understanding how by using a property with multiple values works but using multiple properties with a single value doesn't.

Comment: @bosco_sket no problem. Glad to help. Can you just mark this off as resolved?

Comment: @bosco_sket It does, you have some CSS errors, ill point them out in the bottom of my post

Comment: @bosco_sket added the errors you had, but i would go with the 1 line approach, anytime you can write less code you should

Answer (score 0):

Wow many careless mistakes on my part. Was pretty flustered, doing a lot of poking around in the dark to see if something would work.

HTML

```
                <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Conditions</th>
                        <th>Characteristics</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="row-edge">
                        <td class="first-field">Element</td>
                        <td>version}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first-field">ApplicationTransactionID</td>
                        <td>string, up to 64 chars, Optional</td>
                        <td>A number assigned by the calling application to uniquely identify this request.</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

CSS

```
.row-edge {
    border-top: 1px solid #0A454F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0A454F;
}
```

Changed a few colors and labels. But this is just what I needed.

Thanks again!